# trying to insert data to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

it is connecting to the database but is not inserting values
please help me with inserting the form values into the table registered
`

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $dbconnect = new mysqli('localhost','root','','tas');

    if ($dbconnect) {
        echo "connected to database";
    }
    else{
        echo "did not connect";
    }

    $fname = $_POST["fname"];
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];
    $cert = $_POST["certificate"];
    $sex =  $_POST["sex"];
    $mobile = $_POST["mobile"];
    $email  = $_POST["email"];
    $institution =  $_POST["institution"];
    $session    =   $_POST["session"];
    $media  =   $_POST["media"];

    $insert ="INSERT INTO registered(firstmame,lastname,certificatename,sex,mobile,email,institution,session,media)
     VALUES ($fname,$lname,$cert,$sex,$mobile,$email,$institution,$session,$media)" ;

     if (!$insert) {
        echo "</br>error id not insert";
     }

     else{
        echo"<br/> success";
     }
}
```

?>`

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) You *never* execute the query.

Comment: Where is the part where you are executing the `INSERT` statement ?

Comment: bet you its the missing quotes on the values

Comment: @JakeBall OP is using MySQLi: `$dbconnect = new mysqli('localhost','root','','tas');` Rude.

Comment: I would assume most of those values you're trying to insert are strings and so need quoted. Also, rather than interpolating the variables directly into the query, I suggest you look up prepared statements / parameterised queries to secure your queries. Also, you don't run the insert.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: pls how do i execute the query

Comment: and how do i secure it from injection

Answer (score 4):

Your code is assigning a string value to a variable.

```
$query = "whatever";
```

That's not inserting anything to the database, because that string is never executed as SQL (sent to the database) by your code.

To execute that on the database, you need to use a `mysqli_` function, such as  `mysqli_query()`.

---

Please consider using **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.

Including potentially unsafe values into SQL text leads to SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

NOTE: Character literals in SQL text need to be enclosed in single quotes.

e.g. `VALUES ('abc','def')`   not  `VALUES (abc,def)`.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Here's an example of running an INSERT using a prepared statement with bind placeholders.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO registered
( firstmame
, lastname
, certificatename
, sex
, mobile
, email
, institution
, session
, media
) VALUES 
( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbconnect, $sql)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssss'
        , $fname
        , $lname
        , $cert
        , $sex
        , $mobile
        , $email
        , $institution
        , $session
        , $media 
        );
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    echo "affected rows = " . mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
} else {
   echo "error in prepare " . mysqli_error($dbconnect);
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: pls how do i execute the query am a novice here

Comment: Read, review the examples. All the information is there if you look for it. Don't be lazy @EsemeUkeme http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @EsemeUkeme: I've added a followup in my answer to provide an example of using a **prepared statement** with **bind placeholders** to perform a simple insert. This replaces the line in your code... `$insert = "INSERT...`(It's possible I misspelled something, or missed a semicolon, but this should give you the gist of what it looks like.  See the PHP documentation for more information about the mysqli interface functions. (Pay careful attention to the *arguments* that the functions accept, and what the functions *return*.)

Answer (score 0):

You never execute your `mysqli_query()`. Please execute the query and provide more details.

Comment: while this is part of the issue, they also need to quote all string values in the query.

Comment: To the downvote - how does this NOT answer OPs question? OP wanted to know why it is not inserting, and that is why.

Comment: May the fourth be with you @Dagon